# change img src and width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I change the scr of an img tag using jQuery, such as,

```
$("#img1").attr("src", "pic1.png");
```

after this, I try to get the width of img (it's not set in html),

```
$("#img1").width();
```

it seems the width is not changed with the src, did I miss something? thanks.

Comment: Is `width` set on the image in your CSS at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to do it immediately, it may be because the image isn't fully loaded yet.

Add a single load handler to the image using `.one()`.

```
$("#img1").attr("src", "pic1.png").one('load',function() {
    alert($(this).width());
});
```

or in case the image was cached, you can try this:

```
$("#img1").attr("src", "pic1.png").each(function() {
    if( this.complete ) {
        alert($(this).width());
    } else {
        $(this).one('load',function() {
            alert($(this).width());
        });
    }
});
```

---

As noted by [@Humberto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126052/humberto), you were using `scr` instead of the proper `src`.

Comment: Isn't it the `src` attribute?

Comment: @Humberto: Yes, I missed that. Updated. Thanks. :o)

Comment: +1 @PatrickDw will this work in IE as well? i remember doing the `load` on nivo-slider(jquery plugin) and it worked everywhere except IE. it was for dynamic loading image into the slider

Comment: @kjy112: Strange. I'm not aware of any issues with `.load()`, but I'll try to test later on. I'll post here if I find anything interesting.

Comment: @PatrickDw no sweat i'll just post as a question on SO thanks for the tip! =)